Sedona + Flink JDBC and Postgis data types (UUID, Geography)
I was trying to connect to Postgres (Postgis) and retrieve data from tables which have UUID and Geography columns:
CREATE TABLE area_of_interest (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    geometry public.geography(multipolygon, 4326) NULL
    CONSTRAINT "id_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

I saw already the question Flink JDBC UUID – source connector and that solution does not work with Flink 1.18.
I tried to register the table by using the following approaches but they fail:
TableDescriptor
    .forConnector("jdbc")
    .option(...)
    ...
    .schema(
        Schema.newBuilder()
            .column("id", DataTypes.STRING().notNull()) // doesn't work -> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.UUID and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
            // .column("id", DataTypes.RAW(UUID.class).notNull())  // doesn't work -> Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: The PostgreSQL dialect doesn't support type: RAW('java.util.UUID', '...') NOT NULL.
            .column("geometry", DataTypes.STRING().notNull()) // doesn't work -> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
            // .column("geometry", DataTypes.RAW(Geometry.class))  // doesn't work -> Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: The PostgreSQL dialect doesn't support type: RAW('org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry', '...')
            // .columnByExpression("geometry", "cast(geometry as varchar)") // doesn't work -> Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Unknown identifier 'geometry'
            // .columnByExpression("geometry", "ST_asEWKT(geometry)") // doesn't work -> Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Unknown identifier 'geometry'
            .primaryKey("id")
            .build())
        .build()

Error when trying to map the java.util.UUID (Postgres column is uuid) column to java.lang.String:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.UUID and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.lambda$createInternalConverter$224afae6$10(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:176) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.lambda$wrapIntoNullableInternalConverter$ea5b8348$1(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:127) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.toInternal(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:78) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataInputFormat.nextRecord(JdbcRowDataInputFormat.java:257) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataInputFormat.nextRecord(JdbcRowDataInputFormat.java:56) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]

Error when trying to map the Geography (Postgres column is geography(multipolygon, 4326)) column to java.lang.String:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.lambda$createInternalConverter$224afae6$10(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:176) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.lambda$wrapIntoNullableInternalConverter$ea5b8348$1(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:127) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.converter.AbstractJdbcRowConverter.toInternal(AbstractJdbcRowConverter.java:78) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataInputFormat.nextRecord(JdbcRowDataInputFormat.java:257) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataInputFormat.nextRecord(JdbcRowDataInputFormat.java:56) ~[flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.2-1.18.jar:3.1.2-1.18]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.InputFormatSourceFunction.run(InputFormatSourceFunction.java:97) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]

I'd like to ask what is the supposed way to map those types from Postgis to Flink Table & SQL API or other approach that would help me connect to Postgis and retrieve column with those types.
I tried to map those columns using different approaches with no success.

I know I can create a view on Postgres and "remap" the column types, but I'm interested in a solution that avoids changes on the database if possible :)

I'm a newbie on Flink and from my point of view it seems that Sedona SQL "doesn't enhance" Flink's JDBC Connector to support the extra types from Postgis.

To overcome this issue, I've created a view in Postgres:
create or replace
view vw_area_of_interest as
select
    id::text as id,
    st_asewkb(cast(geometry as geometry)) as geometry
from
    area_of_interest
where
    geometry is not null;

And used the schema like this:
Schema.newBuilder()
    .column("id", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
    .column("geometry", DataTypes.BYTES().notNull())
    .primaryKey("id")
    .build())

